# Image of Complexe Unit Square under the map $f(z)=\frac { 1 }{ z } $

Tags: complex-analysis

I'd like to find the image of the Unit square in the complex plane (vertices 0,1,i,i+1) under the Möbius Transformation $f(z)=\frac { 1 }{ z } $.
I did plug in the values of the corner points to see on which point they get mapped.We have

$0\rightarrow \infty \quad 1\rightarrow 1\quad i\rightarrow -i\quad i+1\rightarrow \frac { 1 }{ i+1 } $
So the image would be the Unit square in the 4.Quadrant? 
But i think this is wrong because one needs to evaluate the lines connecting these points? How would i do this?
Since im very new to complexe analysis some explanation on the line of thought would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you know that a Möbius transformation maps a line onto a line or a circle? And that it preserves angles and orientation?

Comment: Also that this specific transformation inverts modulus and negates argument?

Comment: Also, you might find it useful to state the vertices in the correct order to start with, viz., 0, 1, 1+i, i.

Comment: Also, the fact that 0 maps to $\infty$ should be a clue that this isn't getting mapped to a unit square but to *most* (but not all) of the 4th quadrant, including (but not limited to) all complex numbers in the 4th quadrant with a modulus greater than 1.

Comment: yes i know that lines map to lines or circles, Under the stated preservations we have than that the line segment from 0,1 and 0,i gets mapped onto the same line but how can i evaluted this properly